# Set the color of a tikz-cd Glyph arrow tip with xelatex

Tags: xetex, color, arrows, tikz-cd

I'm using a `Glyph` tip from `tikz-cd` to get arrows like `\looparrowright` and friends.

However I would like to change the color. `latex` compiles the following MWE correctly, but `xelatex` leaves the loop black while coloring the rest of the arrow red.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{
  loop/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=looparrowleft, swap]},
  loop'/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=looparrowleft]}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar[r, loop->, red] & B \\
    % This arrow is red, but the loop part of the tip is black.
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to pass `red` after `swap` in `loop` style definition. That is, `loop/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=looparrowleft, swap, red]},`

Comment: The entire arrow, line and tip, becomes red for me.

Comment: So, do you want only the arrow tip in red color?

Comment: Your MWE produces here in black the letters `A` and `B` and in red the arrow from `A` to `A`.

Comment: My MWE doesn't seem to be working correctly then with the tikz setting. It is supposed to be producing an arrow from A to B with a style matching `\looprightarrow` from `amssymb` and I would like this entire arrow to be red.

Comment: After some digging around: My MWE compiles correctly (gives the desired effect) with LaTex but not with XeLaTeX. I will update the question, but I suspect this is a XeLaTeX bug.......

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/750). There are multiple color problems with XeLaTeX and PG/TikZ. Compile with pdfLaTeX and then with XeLaTeX: `\color{blue}a\begin{pgfpicture}\pgftext{a}\end{pgfpicture}`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to the [same old XeLaTeX problems](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/750) PGF/TikZ has when it comes to colors.

As an alternative to fixing `\pgftext` or somehow sneaking another color `\color` command inside, here's an arrow tip `Loop` that draws something similar. This uses only arc (with radius `inset`) in a loop with diameter `length` (± linewidth fuzziness). The `\looparrowleft` glyph you use seem to use a Bézier curve instead of an arc with a fixed radius. If that is expected, a few adjustments and fiddling around with good controls values are needed.

You can fill the loop part, you can `swap` it and `reversed` with in my opinion pretty good results.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = Loop,
  parameters = {\the\pgfarrowlength,\the\pgfarrowinset,\ifpgfarrowopen o\fi},
  setup code =
    \ifdim\pgfarrowlength<\dimexpr2\pgfarrowinset+\pgflinewidth\relax
      \pgfarrowlength\dimexpr2\pgfarrowinset+\pgflinewidth\relax
    \fi
    \pgfarrowssettipend{\pgfarrowlength}%
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{.5\pgflinewidth}%
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowinset,
  defaults = {length = +3pt +.3 +0, inset = +.75pt +1 +0},
  drawing code={%
    \pgfsetroundcap
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.5\pgflinewidth}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\pgfarrowlength-.5\pgflinewidth-\pgfarrowinset}
                             {0pt}}%
    \pgfpatharc{+-90}{+0}{+\pgfarrowinset}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\pgfarrowlength-.5\pgflinewidth}
                             {\dimexpr\pgfarrowlength-.5\pgflinewidth-\pgfarrowinset}}%
    \pgfpatharc{+0}{+90}{+\pgfarrowinset}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\pgfarrowinset+.5\pgflinewidth}
                             {\dimexpr\pgfarrowlength-.5\pgflinewidth}}%
    \pgfpatharc{+90}{+180}{+\pgfarrowinset}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\pgfarrowinset+.5\pgflinewidth-\pgfarrowinset}
                             {\dimexpr-\pgfarrowlength+.5\pgflinewidth}}%
    \ifpgfarrowopen\pgfusepathqstroke\else\pgfusepathqfillstroke\fi}}
\tikzset{
  Math Loop/.tip  = { Glyph[glyph math command=looparrowleft] },
  Loop Left/.tip  = {Loop[open, swap]},
  Loop Right/.tip = {Loop[open]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \ar[r, {Loop Left - Loop Right[blue]}, red] & B \\
  C \ar[r, /tikz/arrows={Loop Right[fill=pgfstrokecolor!50!yellow]
                       - Loop Left[yellow!80!black, reversed]}, green] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\color{blue}a \begin{pgfpicture}\pgftext{a}\end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]